# Sauce Labs Karma configuration for Chrome Headless

Tags: karma-runner, google-chrome-headless, saucelabs

I have a Karma configuration file setup for Sauce Labs. Here's what the `customLaunchers` section looks like:

```
var customLaunchers = {
    sl_desktop_chrome: {
        base: 'SauceLabs',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        platform: 'Windows 10',
        version: '53'
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make this work for Chrome Headless?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following configuration file to run karma tests on headless chrome

```
  module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    files: ['test/**/*.js'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,  // karma web server port
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    autoWatch: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Run the tests using:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless karma.conf.js"
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to pass custom flags to the headless instance, use

```
customLaunchers: {
      HeadlessChrome: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--disable-translate', '--disable-extensions', '--remote-debugging-port=9223']
      }
    }
```